# Why do I need to wrap function returning a character vector into c() when passing to tidyr ... argument?

Tags: r, tidyr, tidyverse, nse

See example:

```
df <- data.frame(month=rep(1:3,2),
                 student=rep(c("Amy", "Bob"), each=3),
                 A=c(9, 7, 6, 8, 6, 9),
                 B=c(6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 7))
cnames<-function(){c(month="month",student="student")}
```

When wrapping `cnames()` into `c()` the call to `tidyr::gather` works:

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  gather(variable, value, -c(cnames()))
```

but it fails when i call it with `cnames()` or even `(cnames())` only :

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  gather(variable, value, -(cnames()))
```

i.e.

```
> df2 <- df %>% 
+   gather(variable, value, -(cnames()))
Error in -(cnames()) : invalid argument to unary operator
```

I am guessing this has something to do with NSE but what exactly?

Comment: Why are you defining `cnames` as a function and not as vector and simly do `cnames <- c('month', 'student'); df %>% gather(var, val, -cnames)`?

Comment: It is strange that I get the same error after installing to 0.8.0.  For me `df %>% gather(variable, value, -one_of(cnames()))` works as expected

Comment: @akrun indeed strange. Maybe conflicts? Try restarting your session

Comment: @Sotos Why? one possible Answer : `cnames` is a function which computes the column names given the dataframe and an algorithm. A different, you have an OO application. etc etc.

Comment: Yes, ...Why... You have the names set in the function. However, If that is the case, use the function to create the vector and then do the `gather` part (i.e. `v1 = cnames(); df %>% gather(var, val, -v1)`

Comment: @Sotos, You did not understand the question. The question is NOT how to get it working -( I did even provide an example when it works). I would like to understand why it does not when passing cnames() directly? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the 'proper' way of doing it in current `tidyverse`/`tidyselect` would be...

```
df %>% gather(variable, value, -(!! cnames()))
```

The reason `df %>% gather(variable, value, -c(cnames()))` works is because `c()` is specifically handled differently than usual in `tidyselect`. See [string coercion affects `c()` #37](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyselect/issues/37)

`df %>% gather(variable, value, -(cnames()))` does **not** work because the entire expression evalutes (including the `-`), so you get the same error as if you run simply `-(cnames())`